# How to break condition and return data in java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

### some part deleted. that may not necessary now.

I am using following code, My main intention is if condition matched then exit from the loop and return expected data .

In Below list , where  i am getting actual expected list but could not return data, what i am want. I am returning **testting data** value.

```
    public String getlistdata(){
    
    String s = "testting data";
     if(!(this.element==null)){
            ListIterator<ElementData> li = this.element.listIterator();
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();;
            while (li.hasNext()) {
                list.add(li.next().getElemType().toString());
            }
            Log.e("LIST", "TEST LIST"+list+"=="+list.size());
            
            for (String temp : list) {
                System.out.println(temp);
                if (temp.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("group")){
                    s = li.next().getGrpResult();
                      break ;
                }
            }
        }
        return s;
    
    }
```

please identify where i am doing wrong with this code.

## Edited:

I solve above problem of user2310289 answers which is below but problem  i have another problem here again

> I have problem, if i have two or more group here, all time executed
> first group. How to execute second time this method call next group.
> or third time third group. it means how to start this if second time
> call this function, starting index from first groupindex+1 and third
> call this method second groupindex+1 and so on. I have lots of
> confusing here.  aspect ting some  hint
>
> **text, group, group, normal, number, group, text**

Comment: All the answers suggested here work the same as what you already have. The `break` statement, exits the loop and s is returned!!!

Comment: Even with the wonderful answers below, there is still a problem.  Firstly the code `while (li.hasNext()) {` iterates right through the list and later it attempts to `li.next().getGrpResult();` A NoSuchElementException will be thrown - as the iteration has no next element

Comment: Yes i got `java.util.NoSuchElementException`  and `at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:59)` exception, when try my code adding return s. So, How to solve this?Any Idea.

Comment: Look at my updated answer.

Comment: woooo, enough of the Hate man.  Someone downvoted me too. (don't know why)

Comment: How to start ListIterator from the previous found group index if second call this method, and third time call then start ListIterator from the second groupindex. and so on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48562/discussion-between-no-name-code-and-user2310289)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why even bother adding the data to a local `List` in will never be re-used.

**Updated**

Also

Firstly the code `while (li.hasNext()) {` iterates right through the list and later it attempts to `li.next().getGrpResult();` A `NoSuchElementException` will be thrown - as the iteration has no next element

try

```
 String s = "testing data";
 if(!(this.element==null)){
        ListIterator<ElementData> li = this.element.listIterator();
        while (li.hasNext()) {
            ElementData ed = li.next();
            String temp = ed.getElemType().toString();
            System.out.println(temp);
            if (temp.equalsIgnoreCase("group")){
                 return ed.getGrpResult ();
            }
        }

 }
 return null;
```

**Update**

Further to your comment, if you want all matching `ElementData` then instead of `return ed.getGrpResult();`  simply add to an `ArrayList`  `myList.add (ed.getGrpResult ());` and then the code will continue looping.  At the end of the method return the `ArrayList`.

Comment: great, maybe you should remove your `I Hate ...` speech.

Comment: Ok. greatly appreciate your answer.

Comment: I have problem, if i have two or more group here, all time executed first group. How to execute second time this method call next group. or third time third group. it means how to start this if second time call this function, starting index from first groupindex+1 and third call this method second groupindex+1 and so on. I have lots of confusing here. please give hint.

Comment: I have updated my answer with this latest requirement.

Comment: Thank you. your word is very helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `break` use `return s`.

```
if (temp.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("group")){
                    s = li.next().getGrpResult();
                      return s ;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make following change to if condition,

```
 if (temp.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("group")){
                    s = li.next().getGrpResult();
                     return s;
    }
```